# passing data array from any fucntion to other function in laravel

Tags: arrays

How to display all or get the array data in the "function getDataHargaKomoditasPasar" in the "function getRekapDataHome"?

My Script:

```
public static function getDataHargaKomoditasPasar($request)
{ ...
  $dataP = [];
        foreach ($komoditas as $kom) {
            foreach ($hargapangan as $hp) {
                foreach ($hp->detail as $detail) {
                    if ($detail->id_komoditas==$kom->id) {
                        $row = [
                            'id_pasar' => $hp->id_pasar,
                            'harga_minggu_lalu' => $detail->harga,
                            'id_komoditas' => $kom->id,
                            'nama_komoditas' => $kom->nama,
                        ];
                        $dataP[]=$row;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        echo var_dump($dataP);
        return $dataP;
 }

public static function getRekapDataHome($request, $dataRataHargaPerKomoditasHome, $dataHargaKomoditasPasar)
{ ...
 if (isset($request->komoditas)) {
                    foreach ($dataHargaKomoditasPasar as $rataHarga1) {
                       if ($p->id == $rataHarga1['id_pasar']) {
                          echo  $rowPasar['id_pasar'] = $rataHarga1['id_pasar'];
                          echo $rowPasar['harga_minggu_lalu'] = $rataHarga1['harga_minggu_lalu'];
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
....
}
```

RESULT:
1:function getDataHargaKomoditasPasar
array(3) { [0]=> array(4) { ["id_pasar"]=> int(1) ["harga_minggu_lalu"]=> string(8) "14000.00" ["id_komoditas"]=> int(1) ["nama_komoditas"]=> string(13) "Beras Premium" } [1]=> array(4) { ["id_pasar"]=> int(2) ["harga_minggu_lalu"]=> string(8) "13800.00" ["id_komoditas"]=> int(1) ["nama_komoditas"]=> string(13) "Beras Premium" } [2]=> array(4) { ["id_pasar"]=> int(10) ["harga_minggu_lalu"]=> string(8) "13500.00" ["id_komoditas"]=> int(1) ["nama_komoditas"]=> string(13) "Beras Premium" } }

2:function getRekapDataHome (only one data)
114000.00

Thank you.

```
if (isset($request->komoditas)) {
                    foreach ($dataHargaKomoditasPasar as $rataHarga1) {
                       if ($p->id == $rataHarga1['id_pasar']) {
                          echo  $rowPasar['id_pasar'] = $rataHarga1['id_pasar'];
                          echo $rowPasar['harga_minggu_lalu'] = $rataHarga1['harga_minggu_lalu'];
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
....
}
```